# css sprites in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I'm using the following code for star rating. The code works fine in firefox but it sucks (as usual) in IE6. The stars doesn't even show up in IE6, though they work perfectly.
it uses sprites to display the stars. Also, I've fixed the PNG transparency issue with IE6.

```
<div id="ajaxratemasuga"><div class="ratingblock">
    <ul style="width: 90px;" class="rating" id="unit_ul1730">
        <li style="width: 0px;" class="current-rating">Currently 0.00/3</li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" class="r1-unit rater" title="1 out of 3" href="javascript:direct_rating1('/videos-103415','1','1730','59.92.50.233','5','0')">1</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" class="r2-unit rater" title="2 out of 3" href="javascript:direct_rating1('/videos-103416','2','1730','59.92.50.233','5','0')">2</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" class="r3-unit rater" title="3 out of 3" href="javascript:direct_rating1('/videos-103417','3','1730','59.92.50.233','5','0')">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div></div>
```

CSS

```
.rating {
    -moz-background-clip:border;
    -moz-background-inline-policy:continuous;
    -moz-background-origin:padding;
    background:transparent url(../images/starrating.png) repeat-x scroll left top;
    height:30px;
    list-style-image:none;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

.unit-rating a.r1-unit:hover {
    width:18px;
}

.unit-rating a.r1-unit {
    left:0;
}

.unit-rating li a {
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    outline-color:-moz-use-text-color;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:medium;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    width:18px;
    z-index:20;
}
```

I'm not sure whether I've provided all the CSS necessary. If u need more please to analyse please comment.

Comment: Can you post the css from the source CSS file? It looks like you might have copied the CSS out of the Firebug inspector. This is only part of the code. Also, please let us know how you fixed the PNG transparency. It will have bearing on a solution we can provide.

Comment: it's very BIG to post it as a comment so i've given the code below dcneiner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the twin helix solution does not let background images repeat. You are better off using [DD_BelatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/), which allows background repeat and positioning.

Comment: but the images are loaded through a javascript like this :

href="javascript:direct_rating1('/videos-103415','1','1730','59.92.50.233','5','0')"

will DD_BelatedPNG still work?

Comment: The background image used in UL is loaded via CSS. All you need to do is to assign a class (say "png") to every element that uses a png as bg image or an image element that sources a png file.

Comment: i tried this one:

 <script src="DD_belatedPNG.js"></script>
<script>

  DD_belatedPNG.fix('.r1-unit rater, .r3-unit rater, .r2-unit rater, #unit_ul2405, .unit-rating, .current-rating');
  
</script>

but it didn't help..does DD_belatedPNG supports hover pseudo class? i think that could be the problem..but by default, it should show the stars(all 3)..this thing drives me crazy :)